# Forms without an active record model and displaying preexisting database data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a database with data in the format of (country, LEmale, LEfemale) LE = life expectancy, and I want to show this data to a user submitting this form:

```
<%= form_tag "pages#show" do %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:sex, "male") %>
  <%= label_tag(:male, "I am male") %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:sex, "female") %>
  <%= label_tag(:female, "I am female") %>
  <br>
  <%= label_tag(:country, "Country:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:country) %>
  <br>
  <%= number_field_tag 'age', nil, in: 10...110 %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit", :id => 'submit')  %>
<% end %>
```

On the same page, but I am unsure about how to accomplish this, given that I don't have a preexisting active record model to reference. So far I've written the following code, but the form doesn't work, as nothing happens when i press submit.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    @sex = params[:sex]
    @country = params[:country]
    @age = params[:age].to_i    
    @left = Country.new.time_left(@country, @sex, @age)
    redirect_to index
  end
end
```

and my "wrapper model"

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base

  def time_left(country, sex, age)
    data = Country.find(country)
    sex == "male" ? expected = data.male.to_i : expected = data.female.to_i
    left = expected - age
  end  
end
```

What would be the most optimal way to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you expecting to pull database data without a model?

Comment: I use the country model as a wrapper model

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a valid url for the form to submit to in your form_tag.  Given your code  looks like a restful controller, I assume you have a `resources :pages` in your *routes.rb* file so you need to do something like `form_tag "/pages/1", method: "get" do` in order that the route will be matched.

I would suggest creating a more suitably named resource and use a "collection" route like *index* instead of a "member" route like *show*. Or add an extra collection route to it which responds to *POST* requests.

Or alternatively, you can create a singular resource.

However, your code as-is won't do what you expect once you do submit the data to the controller, because you'll lose your `@left` data after the redirect you're doing. If you plan to show the data, you'd need to render a view there.  The simplest approach to take would be to create a new resource with `new` and `create` actions. The new action holds your form and submits to the create action which simply displays the results in the `create.html.erb` template, you shouldn't redirect elsewhere. You can find more information about the request/response cycle in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)